# comparing numbers from two files in c; using fopen etc

Tags: c

I am trying to open two files from inside the code, but I am having trouble trying to get my three numbers from first.txt but it only prints the first one. I just need help printing all the numbers from my text file so no need to finish my whole program but advice is welcomed :)!

```
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
    int *number1Pointer = malloc(80 * sizeof(int));
    FILE *file1;
    //FILE *file2;
    file1 = fopen("first.txt", "r");
    //file2 = fopen("second.txt", "r");

    int read = fscanf(file1, "%d", number1Pointer);

    if(read != '\0')
    {
            printf("%d", &number1Pointer);
    }
    else
    {
            fclose(file1);

    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to read 3 numbers, then you could try with this code

```
int read = fscanf(file1, "%d %d %d", &number1Pointer[0], &number1Pointer[1], &number1Pointer[2]);
```

The variable read will have the number of elements read or EOF. Hence, the check will have to be adapted.

Answer (score 1):

`int read = fscanf(file1, "%d", number1Pointer);` will just read one "%d" like `scanf("%d", &num)` from stdin.

You can either use a while loop or `fscanf(file1, "%d%d%d", ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

If your file contains three numbers separated by a space - i.e. `21 32 32` - you need a format string matching that format:

```
fscanf(file1, "%d %d %d", &number1Pointer[0], &numberPointer[1], &numberPointer[2]);
```

Remember to `free()` your allocated variable after using it.